# Choosing the range of the correlogram with an irregularly shaped area

Tags: correlation, autocorrelation

I am doing correlograms (Moran's I) between 125 plots. Those plots are located in large patches in my study area (see figure).

The entire study area is approximately 2000 x 2000 m. I know that the usual range for a correlogram is 1/2 the value of the length of the study area. But in my case, there is large section of the 2000 x 2000 area that are not sampled.

How to choose the range of my correlogram?

[image: Study area, each point is a plot]